# How to programmatically diffrenciate the epub fix layout and reflowable

Tags: c#, metadata, epub, windows-api-code-pack, epub3

I need to programmatically identify the layout of an ePub file. The ePub file can be either in Fixed Layout or Reflowable Layout.

I tried to use Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack with Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell to pull the metadata of an ePub file.

However, I am not able to identify a property can tell me what the layout is.

Is there any hidden property in the metadata that should focus on?

-Alan-

Comment: Which library you are using for epub? are you building app for mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look for the `<meta property="rendition:layout">` element in the `<metadata>` section of the OPF file:

1. `<meta property="rendition:layout">reflowable</meta>` indicates a reflowable EPUB
2. `<meta property="rendition:layout">pre-paginated</meta>` indicates a fixed layout EPUB

Specification: http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-publications.html#meta-properties-rendering

Note: EPUB 3 allows hybrid EPUBs (i.e., mixing reflowable and pre-paginated spine items), so the property might be attached to spine elements. See the `rendition:layout*` properties: http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-publications.html#sec-itemref-property-values

Comment: Unfortunately most of our OPF file dont have the <meta property="rendition:layout">

Comment: Per http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-publications.html#fxl-property-layout-usage , you should then assume that the EPUB is reflowable: "The default value reflowable must be assumed by EPUB Reading Systems as the global value if no meta element carrying this property occurs in the metadata section."

Comment: If you want an extra heuristic, since FXL requires you to specify a viewport meta element in the header of XHTML files, you can look for it. If you do not find it, the EPUB is reflowable, otherwise FXL. (See: http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-publications.html#fxl-property-layout-values )